# Django form wizard save data into PostgreSQL

Tags: django, django-formwizard, formwizard

I'm creating two form using `form wizard`.

When the user finish fill in the `first form(personal details)`, then select next button, it will go to `second form(family member's details)`.

When the user select submit button, the data will save into specific table(Details and Family). My database engine is PostgreSQL.

Here is my code in view:

```
FORMS = [("customer", CustomerForm),
         ("family", FamilyForm)]

TEMPLATES = {"customer": "customer_register.html",
             "family": "family_register.html",}

def cust_contact_register(wizard):
    cleaned_data = wizard.get_cleaned_data_for_step('customer') or {'method': 'none'}
    return cleaned_data['method'] == 'family'

class CustWizard(SessionWizardView):
    template_name = 'customer_register.html'
    # def get_template_names(self):
    #     return [TEMPLATES[self.steps.current]]

    def done(self, form_list,form_dict,**kwargs):
        form_data= [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list]
        for form in form_data:
            name = form['name']   ## I want to get the data here to save nto database but it return error.
            mobile = form['mobile']
            email = form['email']
            familyname = form['familyname']
            address = form['address']
        add_member = Customer(
            name=name,
            mobile=mobile,
            email=email,
        )
        add_family = Family(
            famname=famname,
            address=address,
        )
        add_member.save()
        add_family.save()
        return render(self.request, 'customer_register.html', {
            'form_data': form_data,
        })
```

Customer table have `id`,`name`,`mobile`,`email`,and `familyid`(Foreign Key) attribute where Family table have `id`,`name` and `address` attribute.

The error returned:

```
Traceback:

File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\formtools\wizard\views.py" in dispatch
  248.         response = super(WizardView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\formtools\wizard\views.py" in post
  309.                 return self.render_done(form, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\formtools\wizard\views.py" in render_done
  365.         done_response = self.done(final_forms.values(), form_dict=final_forms, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\customers\views.py" in done
  1543.             name= form['name']

Exception Type: KeyError at /customer/register/
Exception Value: 'name'
```

But when i tried this in customer_register.html, the data can be display:

```
{% for form in form_data %}
    Name: {{ form.name }}
    Mobile: {{ form.mobile }}
    email: {{ form.email }}
    ......
{% endfor %}
```

**UPDATED**

```
class CustomerForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=50,required=True)
    mobile = forms.CharField(max_length=50,required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=50,required=True)

class FamilyForm(forms.Form):
    famname = forms.CharField(max_length=50,required=True)
    address = forms.CharField(max_length=50,required=True)
```

Comment: You need to show CustomerForm and FamilyForm. Do they both have `name` fields? If they're identical, why do you have two separate form classes at all?

Comment: I have included the form. Cutomer and Family have different value, one is customer name and another one is family name. I create two seperate form because of the first form data will store into Customer table and the second form data will store into Family table.

Comment: You're looping through the forms' `cleaned_data` with `for form in form_data` but the forms are different so they have different fields. You should use the `form_dict` and explicitly reference your forms: `name = form_dict['customer'].cleaned_data['name']`

Comment: I get the same error `exception value:'customer'` @dirkgroten

Comment: that's not possible, the form_dict has a customer key. You're doing something else than what I said.

Comment: yea, Im seeking help too..